# How to get serial number from Mac hard disks?

Tags: macos, cocoa

Is there an easy way to get the serial number of all the hard disks in a Mac using an API?

Basically, I'm looking for a unique identifier for the hard disk with which I can figure out whether the hard disk has been used (or referred to) by my application or not.

Please let me know if there is any other solution.

Note: I need this solution for 10.4 and above.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm not sure if "AppleUSBEHCI" is the proper thing to look for but you can retrieve this sort of data using the IOKit framework:

```
#include <IOKit/IOKitLib.h>
#include <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

kern_return_t   kr;
io_iterator_t   io_objects;
io_service_t    io_service;

kr = IOServiceGetMatchingServices(kIOMasterPortDefault,
            IOServiceNameMatching("AppleUSBEHCI"), &io_objects);

if(kr != KERN_SUCCESS)
    exit(1);

while((io_service= IOIteratorNext(io_objects)))
{
    kr = IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperties(io_service, &service_properties, kCFAllocatorDefault, kNilOptions);
    if(kr == KERN_SUCCESS)
    {
        NSDictionary * m = (NSDictionary *)service_properties;
        NSLog(@"%@", m);
        CFRelease(service_properties);
    }

    io_iterator_t   iter;
    //handle kr error
    kr = IORegistryEntryGetChildIterator(io_service, kIOServicePlane, &iter);

    io_registry_entry_t     child;
    while( (child = IOIteratorNext( iter )))
    {
        kr = IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperties(child, &child_props,  kCFAllocatorDefault, kNilOptions );
        NSLog(@"Child props: %@", child_props);
        //release child_props
    }

    IOObjectRelease(io_service);
}

IOObjectRelease(io_objects);
```

Comment: AppleAHCIDiskDriver - not resulting hard disk which are connected are USB.

By looking in system profiler  USB HD was using
"Host Controller Driver: AppleUSBEHCI"
so I tried using AppleUSBEHCI instead AppleAHCIDiskDriver but did not resulted any result.

not sure I am missing some thing.

Comment: You might want to try mouviciel's answer before you continue on the IOKit path.

For devices connected to USB, do IOServiceNameMatching("AppleUSBEHCI") and then iterate through all its children using IORegistryEntryGetChildIterator(io_service, kIOServicePlane, &iter).

Comment: I appreciate your help. I tied mouviciel solution but did not work.

when I tried using IORegistryEntryGetChildIterator - it return error(268435459), I just called this after IOServiceGetMatchingServices, not sure what am I missing.

Comment: You probably called IORegistryEntryGetChildIterator on the iterator which doesn't make sense.

I've edited my answer to illustrate iterating through children of a ioregistryentry. Note that I've tested with a USB stick - a HDD may or may not appear in the same way. You need to do some reading on IOKit before writing production code.

Comment: it worked, you are right I was called IORegistryEntryGetChildIterator on the iterato.

I will consider your suggestion to read  IOKit before going to production.

thanks for your help.

Comment: is there any way to get 'BSD Name:' in this process. I could see BSD Name in System profiler but I could not see this in the 'child_props' can I get some help on this.

Basically I am trying to map serial number with drive (BSD name - since it is unique).

Comment: you're a genius

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/iokit/1514741-ioiteratornext?language=objc tells that return value of `IOIteratorNext` must be released as well.

Answer (score 9):

From the command line:

`ioreg -rd1 -w0 -c AppleAHCIDiskDriver | grep Serial`

This gives you the serial number of the built-in hard disk.

Comment: update: AppleAHCIDiskDriver is no longer used in newer machines, so this will be empty.  Maybe look for AppleANS2Controller instead.

Answer (score 6):

I think it's better to get the Volume UUID (which appears in the Disk Utility, for example.)
UUID can be obtained using the [Disk Arbitration](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/DiscArbitrationFramework/DADisk_h/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/DADiskCopyDescription) framework, which is slightly higher-level than IOKit and easier to use.
Create `DADiskRef` using `DADiskCreateFromBSDName`, and use `DADiskCopyDescription` to get the info dictionary, and look up the key `kDADiskDescriptionMediaUUIDKey`. Info on the mount point etc. can be obtained by [statfs](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/statfs.2.html).

That said, it might be easier just to invoke the command-line utility [diskutil](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/diskutil.8.html) with the option `-plist` to get the info in the plist format.

The sample code [FSMegaInfo](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/samplecode/FSMegaInfo/) might also be instructive how to get much more info about a disk.

Comment: thanks for valuable information.

As per my understanding UUID is generated in system not sure it can be considered as unique. In my system I am not able to see UUID for the device.

Comment: UUID is an acronym for Universally Unique ID, and it's unique. It's used for example to control what to mount in `/etc/fstab`.
It's also weird that you don't see the UUID. What does `diskutil info /dev/disk0s2` return on your machine? Don't you see the entry `Volume UUID` in the list? You might need to change `/disk0s2` above  to what you actually have. Check first with `diskutil list`.

Comment: a volume ID is conceptually different from a drive ID for a number of reasons, a drive can have multiple volumes, a drive's volumes do not necessary have to be mounted, volumes can be added and removed hence changing their ID even if the drive remains the same

Answer (score 3):

The following will list the serial numbers on the SATA-bus. You don't get to know which device it is as is but you can do it with some scripting/parsing. I've used "sed" to remove all the spaces and "awk" to isolate just the serial in case you are not familiar:

```
$ system_profiler SPSerialATADataType -detailLevel medium | grep Serial | sed -e 's/[\<\>\"\ ]//g' | -F':' '{print $2}'
```

Comment: I guess you can also find this useful:  ->    `$ system_profiler SPSerialATADataType -detailLevel medium | grep -e "Serial" -e "Model" | awk -F': ' '{print $2}'`

Comment: update: SPSerialATADataType not present on newer machines with NVME drives.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [IOKit](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/IOKitFundamentals/Introduction/Introduction.html).

There are two handy tools on your Mac to find out about the possibilities of it:

- ioreg, a command line tool
- IORegistryExplorer, the same with a GUI.

Answer (score 1):

The drive ID's can be retrieved from the IORegistry as follows:

- Internal drives: IOAHCIBlockStorageDevice `string` property "Serial
  Number" inside "Device Characteristics" e.g.: (WD-WCAV5D1345345)
- USB drives : IOUSBDevice `string` property "USB Serial Number"  e.g.:
  (5743415654564561373734)
- FireWire drives : IOReducedBlockServices `number` property "GUID" inside "Protocol Characteristics"  e.g.:
  (407345709348650)
- Thunderbolt drives: ??

These ID's are persistent meaning the same external drives connected to different machines will show the same ID.

Comment: How are they retrieved? What is the complete command?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very old thread and also the first search result so I will add another useful method that relies on installing homebrew and [smartmontools](http://www.smartmontools.org/)

Install [homebrew](https://docs.brew.sh/Installation), then...

```
brew install smartmontools
```

You can then run

```
smartctl -x disk0s3 | grep "Serial Number"
```

You will want to use the `diskutil list` command to find the disk ID

Answer (score -1):

maybe you can just place a hidden file on a hard disk that your app has used? That's e.g. how apple's Time Machine does it.

Comment: good suggestion, I can consider this solution only if get some information from Hard disk. If file is get deleted, I can not recognize it any more in my app.