# Get HDD Serial Number in Swift

Tags: swift, macos

I'm starting a program that needs to keep track of external hard drives.
I'm looking for the best way to uniquely identify a hard drive across several computers (including windows computers with .Net down the road).

I looked at getting the UUID, but that appears to be different across computers.
I was hoping to try to get the manufacturer serial number that's printed on the drive, but I don't know how to do it with Swift, if it's even possible.

Extra bonus if I could also tie this into detecting when a new HDD is mounted, but not a DVD.

Comment: Do you mean something like [this tool](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/135565/how-do-i-get-detailed-smart-disk-information-on-os-x-mavericks-or-later)? It's open source so you could probably dig around in there.

Comment: Interesting info here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2021812/2227743

Comment: @tadman Hmm, yeah, that's interesting... Lots to dig through

Answer (score 2):

Note that `NSFileManager` has this method

```
mountedVolumeURLsIncludingResourceValuesForKeys(_:options:)
```

and under options you can specify `NSURLVolumeIdentifierKey`. This is a temporary identifier (not consistent across restarts) but it is unique and you would be able to monitor newly added or ejected volumes this way.

I am sure there is also another key to tell you about the type of file system and other attributes that let you determine if it is a DVD.

Follow the link to [Common File System Resource Keys](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Common_File_System_Resource_Keys) from the documentation of above method.

Maybe something like

```
let attributes = try manager.attributesOfFileSystemForPath("/")
```

could also be of help. In particular, `NSFileSystemNumber` seems to be a unique number as well.

Comment: hmm... It's kind of important that I find a consistent key, so that I can get the key on my computer, unmount it, take it to another computer, plug it in and get the same key.